# How can I trigger filepond uploads using cypress?

Tags: cypress, filepond

I'm trying to use cypress for writing e2e tests for a media application that handles uploads using [Vue Filepond](https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond), but I have trouble triggering the file uploads. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fair bit of searching I found [this code snippet](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3730#issuecomment-473791017) posted by github user DragorWW

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("uploadFile", (selector, fileUrl, type = "") => {
  return cy.get(selector).then(subject => {
    return cy
      .fixture(fileUrl, "base64")
      .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
      .then(blob => {
        return cy.window().then(win => {
          const el = subject[0];
          const nameSegments = fileUrl.split("/");
          const name = nameSegments[nameSegments.length - 1];
          const testFile = new win.File([blob], name, { type });
          const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
          dataTransfer.items.add(testFile);
          el.files = dataTransfer.files;
          return cy.wrap(subject).trigger('change');
        });
      });
  });
});
```

and it did the trick. After putting it on top of my test file I could simply write

```js
cy.uploadFile("input[type=file]", "some-audio-file.wav", "audio/wav")
```

and the upload got triggered.

Comment: This threw an error for me because the input is covered by `filepond--drop-label` but changing `.trigger('change');` to `.trigger('change', { force: true });` fixed it (if anyone else has this issue).